# Confusion sampling rate of a spatial array

Tags: fft, spatial

I have 1D array data which is a horizontal pixel array with 2048 pixels with 12-bit values.

So I can plot pixel number from zero to 2047 versus pixel values.

But I need the FFT of that 1D array. But in this case there is no time and I use a ready FFT function which requires "samplig rate as input".

What should be the sampling rate in my case?

Comment: Just choose $f_s = 1$ unless the pixel position means something to you.

Answer (score 1):

For an input signal with "domain" unit, $u$, the units of the Fourier Transform's domain are **periods per $u$** or **cyles per $u$**.

For a time-series signal with domain "seconds," the FT domain becomes periods per second, or hertz. Your input sample rate is the number of samples per one second.

If your signal is a spatial sampling - say an amplitude measurement every 0.1 meters - your input domain is in meters and the output domain is periods per meter, or [wavenumber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavenumber). The input sample rate is the number of samples per one meter. For the example stated in this paragraph, that would be a sample rate of $1\text{ sample / }0.1\text{ meter }=10$ samples per meter.

For the case of an image ignoring any spatial relation (i.e. 5 meters per pixel), your input domain can simply be *pixels*. Following the pattern as above, your output domain will be **periods per pixel**. Because each sample is a pixel, your sample rate would just be 1 (one "sample" per pixel). Assuming your data is [bandlimited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandlimiting); by the [Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem), the maximum "frequency" you will be able to resolve is 0.5 periods per pixel, equivalent to one wavelength per two pixels.

Answer (score -1):

In short the answer to Your question is "Sampling rate depends on the **Resolution of the camera** used to capture the 1-D pixel array".

**Details:**

Here is a link to a web page - [Camera Resolution](https://www.photometrics.com/learn/camera-basics/camera-resolution#:%7E:text=In%20imaging%2C%20the%20resolution%20is,more%20than%201%20%C2%B5m%20apart.) talking about this.

In case of space sampling, sampling rate is expressed in inverse length (of appropriate resolution)